# Invading Giant Bats Defeated by Thought Waves of the Insane

Tags: story-identification

Long ago (probably early 1960s) I read a story (possibly a Digit book) about an invasion of Earth by giant bats capable of both telepathy and teleportation. When they met resistance they crushed it by teleporting an H-Bomb from one of Earth's own arsenals. In particular they destroyed Paris as an object lesson. Apparently even the threat from space did not persuade the Powers to destroy these weapons. They remained too suspicious of one another.

The bats were finally defeated by a machine that broadcast human thought waves. Initially it didn't work, until the hero suggested using the thoughts of *insane* persons, as these would disrupt the bats' strictly logical minds.

Does this ring any bells?

Comment: Sorry. I'm pretty sure I've read the Spinrad (wasn't the alien leader called "The Kor"? and it's not the one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes in The Solarians the alien leader was called The Kor. Is the story you're looking for a full length novel or a short story?

Comment: It was definitely a novel, though a relatively slim one. Digit Books did quite a bit of sf in those days.

Comment: Iirc the novel was more or less "contemporary" with the time of writing, ie humans had little or nothing in the way of manned spaceflight.

Comment: Interestingly John Campbell wrote a short story under the pseudonym of Don A. Stuart called "The Cloak of Aesir".  The plot involved alien invasion, telepathy and defeating the aliens by hooking up a human manufactured telepathy broadcast machine to a clinically depressed man in order to disrupt the aliens thoughts - but no nukes or teleportation were involved.  That story was published in 1939.  The book in the OPs answer was published in 1955.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo! I've just found it. It was *The Moon Raiders* by Sydney J Bounds.

I was googling *Digit Books* and spotted a book of that title with a familiar looking cover. Googling the title confirms it.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a bit like **[The Solarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Solarians)** written by Norman Spinrad in 1966 .

It has some points you mentioned like bat-like aliens, mention of threat of using nuclear device and existence of telepaths . Might be wrong tho

[image]